# Apex listener and Glassfish 3 keep give me HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

Tags: glassfish-3, oracle-apex

I stuck a whole day trying to figure this out. 
I already check all setting from step by step documentation. anybody can give me some clue please.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i have to undeploy the apex listener and make sure the server configuration using the right realm and the deploy it again. solved